# How to terminate request from a sub function in golang

Tags: go, go-http

I want to return and terminate request that comes in `checkSomeThing` function. But the problem is the process continues and doesn't return response unless reaches the end of the `main()`. here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    // ...

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    checkSomeThing(w, r)

    http.Error(w, "Operation completed!", http.StatusOK)
    fmt.Println("End of Handler.")
}

func checkSomeThing(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    http.Error(w, "Bad Request!", http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}
```

After run the program here's the output:

```
// Output:    
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Sun, 12 Sep 2021 12:38:49 GMT
< Content-Length: 34
< 
Bad Request!
Operation completed!
```

Comment: where is the `test` function? Did you mean `checkSomeThing`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always try to handle errors at the API level - bubbling errors up the call-stack. There are, however, cases where this is not possible - maybe your handler is one of many in a middleware chain of handlers, and you don't want those other layers to complete. So...

---

If you want to immediately abort a request from your handler, the standard library supports `panic` & recovery.

From the [http.Handler docs](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Handler):

> If ServeHTTP panics, the server (the caller of ServeHTTP) assumes that
> the effect of the panic was isolated to the active request. It
> recovers the panic, logs a stack trace to the server error log, and
> either closes the network connection or sends an HTTP/2 RST_STREAM,
> depending on the HTTP protocol. **To abort a handler so the client sees
> an interrupted response but the server doesn't log an error, panic
> with the value ErrAbortHandler.**

and `http.ErrAbortHandler`:

> ... is a sentinel panic value to abort a handler. While
> any panic from ServeHTTP aborts the response to the client, panicking
> with ErrAbortHandler also suppresses logging of a stack trace to the
> server's error log.

so to do this in your handler:

```
func checkSomeThing(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.Error(w, "Bad Request!", http.StatusBadRequest)
    panic(http.ErrAbortHandler) // terminate request (and any more handlers in the chain)
}
```

There is a catch...

Writes to client will be buffered - and `panic`ing will likely cause these buffered writes to be lost.

To [forcibly flush](https://medium.com/@simonfrey/manual-flush-golang-http-responsewriter-55675bb1415a) the buffer:

```
if f, ok := w.(http.Flusher); ok {
    f.Flush()
}

panic(http.ErrAbortHandler)
```

or you can add your own `panic` recovery. Just ensure, in the recovery, to "re-raise" any `panic`s - if they were not cause by you - so they won't be lost:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    defer func() {
        r := recover()

        switch r {

        case nil: // no panic

        // (2) goes here...
        case http.ErrAbortHandler:
            log.Println("Recovered in handler")

        // (2) or here...
        default:
            panic(r) // re-raise any unexpected panic
        }
    }()
    checkSomeThing(w, r)  // (1) panic here ...

    // (3) ... and this never runs
}
```

in the above panic-recovery code, `http.ServeHTTP` will never know there was a panic - and flush the request buffers naturally.

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was looking for. the recovery method worked fine for me. But you said Its not a good solution. Neither the req recovery method?

Comment: Like most software decisions, the answer is "it depends".  If you can cleanly recover from a handler - go that route. `panic` should not be a substitute for error handling. There may be cases where bubbling up an error through the call stack (maybe a third-party layer is out of your control) is just not feasible and `panic`ing 
 is your only option.

Comment: imho, this is a very reasonable solution given that we don't get to control the chain of handlers from within handlers using current standard API (it might have had an extra return parameters for that purpose).

Comment: @mh-cbon on reflection, I changed my mind. Since the standard library has support for this, this is not a completely "out of bounds" solution. Updated answer accordingly & improved the panic-recovery code to only recover expected panics, letting unexpected ones through.

Answer (score 1):

According to the http.Error documentation

> Error replies to the request with the specified error message and HTTP code.
> It does not otherwise end the request; the caller should ensure no further writes are done to w. The error message should be plain text.

So after executing the `checkSomeThing`  function it just writing the error string in `responsewriter` and continuing processing further operations.

A working version of your code is given below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    // ...

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    err := checkSomeThing(w, r)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    http.Error(w, "Operation completed!", http.StatusOK)
    fmt.Println("End of Handler.")
    return
}

func checkSomeThing(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error{

    http.Error(w, "Bad Request!", http.StatusBadRequest)
    return errors.New("bad request")
}
```

Comment: It works but the reason that I want to do this is separate program logic. Isn't there any way that do not force us to `err` check in `main()` function?

Comment: It's overkill, but you could `panic`. `net/http` `ServeMux` handler detects panics & continues to serve new requests thus avoid the entire service to end.

Comment: Could you post your answer please? @colm.anseo

Comment: But I don't think panicking is a good solution. And while writing server in golang you should return error from validator function then handle it in usecase or handler function. In python you could raise validation error from anywhere easily.